# How send text to HTTP POST?

Tags: ios, http, post, request, comments

In my app I am using this code for sending parameters name, email, website url and comment in blog...Probably some value are wrong setting...Someone can help me solved? I'm going crazy!! Thanks in advance!

```
-(void)invia{



        [self.connessione cancel];

            NSURL *indirizzo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://*********ina.altervista.org/********/feed/"];

            //initialize a request from url
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[indirizzo standardizedURL]];

            [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
            [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


            NSDictionary *parametri = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    campoSito.text, @"url",
                                    campoNome.text, @"author",
                                    campoEmail.text, @"email",
                                    campoCommento.text, @"content", nil];

            NSString *dati_postati=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",parametri];


            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


            [request setHTTPBody:[dati_postati dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


            //initialize a connection from request
            NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            self.connessione = connection;


            //start the connection
            [connection start];



            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            campoCommento.text=nil;
            campoEmail.text=nil;
            campoSito.text=nil;
            campoNome.text=nil;


}
```

EDIT:

@Rich I've tried to read the API documentation for the web service, more precisely the part which concern "Create a Comment on a Post",I think my site ID concern the article is "gnutella"...I do not think there is a numeric id...from which I extract the id?

UPDATE:

I've extract Post ID from article...is 1757
I've tried with this URL without success

```
NSURL *indirizzo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/gnutella/1757/"];




NSURL *indirizzo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/gnutella/1757/replies/new"];




NSURL *indirizzo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/wp-admin/post.php?post=1757&action=edit"];
```

Another code method:

```
#define kSendCommentJSON @"?json=respond.submit_comment"
        NSURL *completeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/gnutella/feed/"]];

        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:completeURL];

        NSDictionary *parametri = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   campoSito.text, @"url",
                                   campoNome.text, @"author",
                                   campoEmail.text, @"email",
                                   campoCommento.text, @"content", nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:parametri constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            //
        }];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Completed Successfullly");
            //[self commentPostSuccess];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed misurable  %@", [error description]);
            //[self commentPostFailed];
        }];

        [operation start];
```

I've tried with this method...not yet!!
Console return successfully but text is not sent correctly...
Also tested on device(for exclusion a possible bug)...nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the parameters correctly in the format `key=value&key=value`, not just as `description` of a `NSDictionary`.

```
 NSDictionary *parametri = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                campoSito.text, @"url",
                                campoNome.text, @"author",
                                campoEmail.text, @"email",
                                campoCommento.text, @"content", nil];

 NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];

 [parametri enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
     // Create an encoded parameter pair -> k=v
     NSString *p = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [[obj description] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]];
     [values addObject:p];
 }];

 NSString *dati_postati = [values componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
```

UPDATE:

So after looking at the `POST` request that is sent (on [this](http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/gnutella/#comments) page:

```
HTTP POST http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/wp-comments-post.php
Host: zenzeroincucina.altervista.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://zenzeroincucina.altervista.org/gnutella/
Cookie: __cfduid=d1ef25815caa898a777114c04c4d37bfc1398261681664; av_device_cookie=computer; av_mobile_cookie=desktop; PHPSESSID=b27e99a06qrkkd2lenppt9p1i6; __utma=178781179.1711693902.1398262580.1398262580.1398262580.1; __utmc=178781179; __utmz=178781179.1398262580.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Connection: keep-alive

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 201

author=Test&email=test%40stack.com&url=stackoverflow.com&comment=Test&captcha_code=dw3P&submit=Submit+Comment&comment_post_ID=1757&comment_post_ID=1757&comment_parent=0&akismet_comment_nonce=f8393add8f
```

This doesn't massively help however as you need to include the *captcha*.

What you want to use is the [WordPress API](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/post/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/replies/new/) for posting comments. I played around with this but I don't have your site ID.

Comment: I tried but the results are the same as before ... the text is not posted ... any other ideas?

Comment: @geminimac What does the API documentation say about the format of the request?

Comment: The API documentation for the web service you are using (from the looks it might be `altervista`?) so we can have a look at it and help diagnose the problem :) Also is there an error that the `POST` returns?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where have you been getting your information from so far?

Comment: I do not know what to do...
I've tried to change the keys of the objects ... nothing!for regard to the API documentation I do not know where to look ... I'm not very good at these things ...how can I move? Thanks

Comment: How do you know you can `POST` to that?!

Comment: You can't just `POST` to a URL lol. Do you own that page? Can I try leaving a comment and seeing what is sent?

Comment: @geminimac I've updated my answer - not looking good, I'm sure you can use the API but I don't know what your WordPress site ID is?

Comment: @geminimac Where have I got WordPress from? Have you ever mentioned that or have I just made that up?!

Comment: then the captha cause problems? you need the username and password of wordpress? otherwise we can not solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
-(void)invia{



    [self.connessione cancel];

    NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url=%@&author=%@&email=%@&content=%@",campoSito.text,campoNome.text,campoEmail.text,campoCommento.text];

    NSURL *indirizzo = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://*********ina.altervista.org/********/feed?%@",param]];

    //initialize a request from url
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[indirizzo standardizedURL]];

    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];




    NSString *dati_postati=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",parametri];


    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [request setHTTPBody:[dati_postati dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //initialize a connection from request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connessione = connection;


    //start the connection
    [connection start];



    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    campoCommento.text=nil;
    campoEmail.text=nil;
    campoSito.text=nil;
    campoNome.text=nil;


}
```